# Android media player can't play, many errors

Tags: android, media-player

I'm trying to implement a recording/play app functionality like WhatsApp, I load a recording listener if I create a new note or a play listener if I load an existing note.
With recording no problem, I can't play track instead. I set the listener in the OnCreateView of a Fragment.

```
audioSendButton.setOnClickListener(new playerListener(path,audioSendButton,context));
```

(i edited the code a lot, sorry if i wrote some stupid things)

```
/**
* Created by Marco on 19/07/2016.
*/
public class playerListener  extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,
    MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

private MusicService musicSrv;
private Intent playIntent;
private boolean musicBound=false;
private String path;
private View playButton;
private boolean playing;
private MediaPlayer player;
private Uri trackUri;
private Context context;

public playerListener(String path, View pb, Context c){
    this.path = path;
    this.playButton = pb;
    this.context = c;
    this.path = path;
    playing = false;
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    initMusicPlayer();
}

public void initMusicPlayer(){
    player.setWakeMode(context, PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    player.setOnErrorListener(this);
    player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener(){
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
    Log.i("music_service","created");

}

public void playSong(){
    player.reset();
    try{
        player.setDataSource(path);
        player.prepareAsync();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Error setting data source", e);
    }


}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(!playing){
            playSong();
            //Toast.makeText(this,"clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i("pressed","true");
            playing = true;
    }
    else{
        if(player!=null) {
            player.stop();
            player.reset();
            player.release();
            playing = false;
            //player=null;
        }

        }



}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    mediaPlayer.release();
    //player = null;
    playing = false;
}

@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
    Log.i("Error","found");
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    mediaPlayer.release();
    //player = null;
    playing = false;
    return false;
}


@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    Log.i("mediaplayer","preparato");
    player.start();

}
}
```

This is the error log, the path is correct, it is an absolute path (/storage/emulated/0/Nota-2016.07.20 17:57:23.mp4)

```
07-20 19:53:15.071 30520-30532/com.marcocreation.****** E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
07-20 19:53:15.071 30520-30520/com.marcocreation.****** E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
07-20 19:53:15.071 30520-30520/com.marcocreation.****** I/Error: found
07-20 19:53:15.072 30520-30520/com.marcocreation.****** E/MediaPlayer: stop called in state 0
07-20 19:53:15.072 30520-30520/com.marcocreation.****** E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
```

Ok, i tried my app on a huawei P8 Lite, so with sd cards, and it works perfectly, so the problem is my nexus 5 with no sdcards (or poor encoding/decoding system?). Any idea to solve it?

Comment: could it be android can't decode the file? i save in mp4 cause with 3gp i had problems with recording, i'll try again hoping it's the problem

Comment: Ok, the problems seems to be the android enconder/decoder (stupid) system. I tried a lot of format but i can play track only with vlc, and no with play music. How can i perform a recording witch integrated media player is able to play?